# what is equivalent for PdfWriter.getInstance(document,response.getOutputStream()); to excel

Tags: java, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I have an option to export the data to PDF, the code is listed below :

```
  response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + title + ".pdf\"");
  PdfWriter.getInstance(document,response.getOutputStream());
```

what is the equivalent option to export `Excel` file like `PdfWriter.getInstance(document,response.getOutputStream());`

also below code is perfect to perform download but it fails to open the `PDF` file when i give open with option.

how to go about.

UPDATE :

this is the code that i use to genarate and export the PDF file, same way is there any way to do for excel file ?

```
if(exportTo.equals("pdf"))
        {
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + title + ".pdf\"");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,response.getOutputStream());

        try {
            document.open();
            addTitlePage(document, "Employee Report Details");

           /* Image image = Image.getInstance(path+"images/abi.png");
            image.setAbsolutePosition(40f, 770f);
            image.scaleAbsolute(70f, 50f);
            document.add(image);*/

            Map headerMap = new LinkedHashMap();
            headerMap = custDAO.getHeader(query);

            float[] colsWidth = {1.5f,3f,4f,4f,2f};
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(colsWidth);
            table.setWidthPercentage(98);
            table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell();
            for (Iterator it = headerMap.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                String headerName = (String) headerMap.get(it.next());
                c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(headerName, headerFont));
                c1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
                table.addCell(c1);
            }
            table.setHeaderRows(1);
            table = custDAO.creadPDFTable(query, table);
            document.add(table);
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refer you to this tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html#createexcel

there's no one best choice for excel exporting. there's a lot of libraries out there.

Comment: not the write one,but it helped me to create the excel file, i am talking about web application not the desktop application